# Cache data with lua script, but getting RedisCommandExecutionException with accessing a non local key in a cluster node

Tags: java, spring-boot, redis, redis-cluster

I have a map data to cache in redis cluster using lua script in springboot project, such as:

```
{
    "demoKey:{1}":"value1",
    "demoKey:{2}":"value2",
    "demoKey:{3}":"value3"
}
```

lua script like this:

```
local addMap = cjson.decode(ARGV[1]);

for fieldKey, fieldValue in pairs(addMap) do
    redis.call("SET", fieldKey, fieldValue);
end
```

JAVA CODE:

```
final DefaultRedisScript<?> redisScript = new DefaultRedisScript<>();
redisScript.setScriptSource(LUA_SCRIPT);
redisClient.execute(redisScript, new ArrayList<>(), JsonUtil.toString(addMap));
```

I have set the `hash tag` in redis key, but I still get the exception while running the program.

```
org.springframework.data.redis.RedisSystemException: Error in execution; nested exception is io.lettuce.core.RedisCommandExecutionException: ERR Error running script (call to f_7cce57ffe5b0b94fa78680955c993e808ffa5f16):
 @user_script:7: @user_script: 7: Lua script attempted to access a non local key in a cluster node
```

Appreciating for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LUA script does not allow us to access keys that are not on the same Redis machine where the LUA script is running.

One solution is to tag the KEYS so that it will land on the correct Redis node, tagging a key means all keys would belong to the same Redis instance.

It seems you have done tagging using `{1}`, `{2}` and `{3}` but all of these potentially could hash to different Redis instance so leading to the error. Your tag should be the same, for example, you can use `userId`, `recordId` etc as a tag.

For your example, if you can change your map to  below it should be working fine.

```
{
    "demoKey_1:{demoKey}":"value1",
    "demoKey_2:{demoKey}":"value2",
    "demoKey_3:{demoKey}":"value3"
}
```

Comment: It works fine. There is another question. The data would be cached all in the same slot, if   all this master and slave redis server shutdown, can I query the data anymore?

Comment: If all redis instances are shutdown than you can't access data.

Comment: Yes, it is. What I mean is that all redis instances storing `{demoKey}` data are shutdown.  Tagging a key means all keys would belong to the same redis instance, what if this redis instance including master and slave are shutdown, can I access  `{demoKey}` data?

Comment: Even if you don't tag if the nodes having the slots are down would return nothing. That's why we use local cache in some cases so that we can tolerate failure of few milli seconds. Redis would automatically start redistributing key slots so what could potentially happen is the key slot can be assigned to some other new elected master.